# What is RAM prefetch, and how does it influence RAM performance?

Tags: memory, prefetch

I'm trying to understand RAM performance. I've seen [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM#Generations) on Wikipedia, and I understand what each column refers to, except the RAM chipset pre-fetch column. What does this refer to? And why when its value increases, the speed at which the memory bus clock works is multiplied by its value?

Comment: What is your interpretation?

Comment: I don't know what RAM prefetching is. So I don't know how to interpret their values. What I see is that when this value goes up, the memory bus speed goes up, but I don't know why this happens, and if it is a cause or a consequence. I only see this value being multiplied by two in each new generation of DDR, except between the third and the fourth ones.

Comment: https://www.synopsys.com/blogs/chip-design/ddr-generations-memory-density-speed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefetching is simply the practice of requesting or sending more data than was initially requested in the hope that the additional data was likely to be the *next* request.

It has no direct link to bus speed or memory transfers, except in that it uses what might otherwise be empty bus transfer cycles.

The `2n` in that column is saying that DDR will transfer 2 x n "words" where the word is the memory transfer size. For a 64-bit memory it will transfer 2 x 64-bit memory words. Later memories will send 8 x 64 bit words one after another.

The reason it increases with memory frequency is simply to reduce memory bus down-time. The faster the bus runs the more clock cycles could be wasted between a request for memory and the actual data, by increasing the number of memory words pre-fetched you get a tradeoff in less downtime at the cost of potentially sending data no one actually wanted. That time would have been wasted anyway in that case so there is little downside to the prefetched data transfer.